# variables don't update after inheriting from subclass

Tags: android, inheritance, kotlin, subclass

Lets say I'm working on the following code in Kotlin:

```
class Human(var head: Head, var body: Body, var legs: Legs) {
   var height = this.head.length + this.body.length + this.legs.length
}

class Head(var length: Int) { }

class Body(var length: Int) { }

class Legs(var length: Int) { }
```

Why is the correct height `Human.height -> x` returned on initialization but does not update if changes are made to the individual parts? Is my formatting for using these subclasses even correct? I have found some documentation on proper subclass usage but I haven't yet found a structure that matches the use case I have. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is this `java`-related?

Comment: my bad must have snuck in there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your height variable has a backing field, which will be initialized to the value after the `=` sign. It will not be recomputed when you fetch it. So this Kotlin code will be equivalent to the follow Java code:

```
// Kotlin
var height = this.head.length + this.body.length + this.legs.length

// Java
// The backing field
private int height = this.head.length + this.body.length + this.legs.length

public int getHeight() {
    return height;
}

public void setHeight(int height) {
    this.height = height;
}
```

What you really want is to recompute the value every time the `get`-method is called. Since you don't want to actually write to any `height`-field, you can use a `val` instead of a `var`. Like this:

```
// Kotlin
val height: Int
    get() = this.head.length + this.body.length + this.legs.length

// Which is equivalent to this Java code:
public int getHeight() {
    return this.head.length + this.body.length + this.legs.length;
}
```

As you can see, the backing field will be gone because the value will be recomputed every time. There's also no setter, because we are now using a `val`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This got me up and running as well as giving me a better understanding of how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You're not implementing a getter, you simply calculate and assign `height` value when your `Human` is initialized.

What you're looking for is getter implementation:

```
class Human(var head: Head, var body: Body, var legs: Legs) {
    val height
      get() = this.head.length + this.body.length + this.legs.length
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile. You still have a backing field because `height` is `var`, and that means you have to initialize it.

Comment: Right it needs to be a val, unless OP has some idea for setter implementation.